# What is the default class for managing ASP.NET profile properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, profile

In .NET we have the `System.Web.Security.Membership` class which is the standard way to create, delete, search users etc. This uses the underlying membership provider as defined in the web.config file. Likewise, we have the `System.Web.Security.Roles` class for managing the roles assigned to users. I can't see an equivalent class for managing profile properties in that Namespace.

What is the default/analogous class for managing Profile properties?
I've looked at the `System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase` class but the name suggests this should be used as a base class, rather than called directly. Will this class automatically use the defined profile provider referenced in web.config? I don't want a dedicated class here, just something which I can call `SetProperty`, `GetProperty` and `Save`.

Answer (score 0):

It's [System.Web.Profile.ProfileManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.profile.profilemanager?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm looking for a class where I can get/set the property values of a specific user's profile. This seems to support finding/removing the profile objects, but not modifying them.

Comment: For that you need your class that derives from `ProfileBase`.  You can wire it up using `<profile inherits="...">` in web.Config as described here: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class